# Can't a base class pointer which is pointing to derived class access the public data members of base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual-functions, run-time-polymorphism

I have created a base class Polygon and declared two data members - height and width as public. Also a virtual function - calculateArea(). Then the two derived classes rectangle and triangle have a function calculateArea(). I want to override the base class function and each of the derived class use its own calculateArea().
The output is not coming as expected and it is 0 or some random value. You can see the code below and tell me where I am going wrong.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class polygon{  
    public:
        int height;
        int width;
        void setValue()
        {
            cout<<"\nEnter height and width ";
            cin>>height>>width;
        }
        virtual int calculateArea(){
        }
};

//Inheritance
class rectangle:public polygon
{
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        int calculateArea()
        {
            return height*width;
        }
};

class triangle:public polygon
{
    public:
        int calculateArea()
        {
            return (height*width)/2;
        }
};

int main()
{
    polygon p;
    rectangle r;
    triangle t;
    
    polygon* base;
    base = &p;
    base->setValue();
    
    base=&r;
    cout<<"\nArea of rectangle is "<<base->calculateArea();
    
    base=&t;
    cout<<"\nArea of triangle "<<base->calculateArea(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It can. But r's width and height are uninitialized. So are t's width and height.

Comment: You are never setting any width and height for r or t. Also calculateArea in polygon should probably be pure virtual.

Comment: It can.   But before the call of `base->setValue()`, `base` points at `p` so the call of `base->setValue()` reads values of `p.height` and `p.width`.   Then you assign `base` so it points at a `r`, who's `height` and `width` members are unintialised.     `public` access does not mean that `p` and `r` somehow share the same data - they are distinct objects.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 distinct objects in `main`. A `polygon` called `p`, a `rectangle` called `r`, and a `triangle t`. You call `setValue` only on the `polygon` object.

The other objects have their members uninitialized. You should initialize the members and then I suppose you want to call `setValue` for the other instances as well:

```
class polygon{  
    public:
        int height = 0; // initializer for members
        int width = 0;
// ....

// in main
// ok
polygon* base;
base = &p;
base->setValue();

base=&r;
base->setValue(); // <-- this was missing
std::cout<<"\nArea of rectangle is "<<base->calculateArea();

base=&t;
base->setValue(); // <-- this was missing
std::cout<<"\nArea of triangle "<<base->calculateArea();
```